# The function "is_granted" does not exist in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

After installing [Symfony2 cmf](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/getting-started/installing-symfony-cmf.html), when I tried to view the admin / dashboard I have the following error:

> The function "is_granted" does not exist in SonataAdminBundle :: standard_layout.html.twig at line 95

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I struggled with that quite a lot of time, too. Here's how to fix it:

Add the SecurityBundle to `app/AppKernel.php`

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...

        // support for the admin
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    );
    // ...
}
```

Create a `security.yml` in your `app/config` folder, e.g. with this demo content:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:

                realm: "Secured Demo Area"
    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

and load it it your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Just as a feedback to whoever else might face this issue :

acme's solution works. Apparently, users MUST be provided as described in

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorials/creating-cms-using-cmf-and-sonata.html

Comment: This should just have been an up vote for Acme's answer possibly with a comment. your post is not a new answer

Comment: I am really sorry, but I could neither update (due to th elack of reputation) nor could I comment.